# Does Nuxt support Cache Busting?

Tags: caching, browser-cache, nuxt.js

You can find the meaning of cache busting at https://www.keycdn.com/support/what-is-cache-busting.

The main point is that when a new version is deployed, it should use the new feature with avoiding the cached feature.
My app is deployed with Universal SSR and using scss.
I checked the deployed files and css code was included in the html so css is not related to cache busting.
Also, I checked the js file and whenever the js file is built, the filename seems to have changed with some random string. I think it supports cache busting on js file.

My conclusion is that nuxt supports cache busting. Am I right? If then, can you give a proper reference on nuxt website or webpack configuration codes on github??

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think cachebusting is supported because I find myself having to make a page refresh (to clear browser cache) when new code is deployed